# Best way to create toggle 'All', 'Online', and 'Offline' actions with redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I'm creating the freecodecamp twitch API using React and Redux. The idea of the app is that you can search for channels to follow, which will be added to a 'Friends List'. At the top of the friends list is a button group with 3 toggle functions: Show All, Show Online and Show Offline.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. Currently my 'users' state is just an array of users, and each user is an object with 2 keys: `channelData` and `streamData`.

This is because I have to make 2 axios calls to the twitch API: one to get general channel information (such as logo url, channel name), and the other to find out if the channel was currently online or offline.

`actions/index.js`:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_USER = 'FETCH_USER';
export const HAS_ERRORED = 'HAS_ERRORED';
export const SELECTED_USER = 'SELECTED_USER';
export const SHOW_ONLINE = 'SHOW_ONLINE';
export const SHOW_OFFLINE = 'SHOW_OFFLINE';
export const SHOW_ALL = 'SHOW_ALL';

const ROOT_URL = 'https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/';

export function fetchUser(user) {
  const channelUrl = `${ROOT_URL}/channels/${user}`;
  const streamUrl = `${ROOT_URL}/streams/${user}`;

  const request = axios.all([
    axios.get(channelUrl),
    axios.get(streamUrl)
  ]);

  return (dispatch) => {
    request.then(axios.spread((channelData, streamData) => {
      var channelData = channelData.data;
      var streamData = streamData.data;

      if (channelData.error) {
        dispatch(hasErrored(channelData.message));
      }
      else {
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_USER,
          payload: { channelData, streamData }
        });
        dispatch(hasErrored(null));
      }
    }));
  }
}

export function hasErrored(msg) {
  return {
    type: HAS_ERRORED,
    msg
  }
}

export function selectUser(user) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(hasErrored(null));
    dispatch({
      type: SELECTED_USER,
      user
    });
  }
}

export function showOnline() {
  return {
    type: SHOW_ONLINE
  }
}

export function showOffline() {
  return {
    type: SHOW_OFFLINE
  }
}

export function showAll() {
  return {
    type: SHOW_ALL
  }
}
```

Then when depending which button is clicked either a SHOW_ALL, SHOW_ONLINE or SHOW_OFFLINE action will be made, which at the moment, simply filters 
the current state to see if that user's streamData is showing it is online or not. But the problem with this method is when I click one button, e.g. SHOW_ONLINE, it will list all the Online users and won't store all the Offline users somewhere, so when I click SHOW_OFFLINE after that,

`reducers/reducer_users.js`:

```
import { FETCH_USER, SHOW_ONLINE, SHOW_OFFLINE, SHOW_ALL } from '../actions/index';

export default function(state = [], action) {

  switch(action.type) {


    case FETCH_USER:
    return [action.payload, ...state];

    case SHOW_ONLINE:
    return state.filter(user => {
      return user.streamData.stream;
    });

    case SHOW_OFFLINE:
    return state.filter(user => {
      return !user.streamData.stream;
    });

    case SHOW_ALL:
    return state;

  }
  return state;
}
```

`containers/users_list.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { selectUser, showOnline, showOffline, showAll } from '../actions/index';

class UsersList extends Component {

  renderUser(user) {
    const { channelData, streamData } = user;

    return (
      <tr
        key={channelData.display_name}
        onClick={() => this.props.selectUser(user)}
        className='list-item'>
        <td>
          <img src={channelData.logo} className='user-logo' />
        </td>
        <td>
          {channelData.display_name}
        </td>
        <td>
          {streamData.stream ?
            <span className='online'>Online</span> :
            <span className='offline'>Offline</span>}
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }

  render() {
    console.log('state:', this.props.users);
    return (
      <div className='col-sm-4'>
        <div className='text-center'>
          <div className='btn-group btn-group-sm' role='group'>
            <button
              className='btn btn-default'
              onClick={this.props.showAll}>
              All
            </button>
            <button
              className='btn btn-default'
              onClick={this.props.showOnline}>
              Online
            </button>
            <button
              className='btn btn-default'
              onClick={this.props.showOffline}>
              Offline
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <table className='table table-hover'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Logo</th>
              <th>Channel</th>
              <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.props.users.map(this.renderUser.bind(this))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ users }) {
  return { users };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { selectUser, showOnline, showOffline, showAll })(UsersList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your problem is a matter of sorting, filtering etc. while keeping a ref to the original state.

consider the following problem :

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4];

let newArr = arr.filter((item)=>{ return item > 2 });
```

the `newArr` (which is your new state, in your case) is now missing items. if you'd ever want to see the original list, you can't.

You'll want to keep a clean copy of the data before you do any modifications to it, this way whenever you filter, you always start fresh.

A simpler reducer would look like this

```
function(state = {}, action) { //notice state is an object

  switch(action.type) {

    case FETCH_USER:
        let newState = Object.assign({},state);
        newState['pristine'] = Object.assign({},action.payload); 
        newState['filteredData'] = Object.assign({},action.payload);
    return newState;

    case SHOW_ONLINE:
       let data = Object.assign({},state.pristine);
       let filteredData = data.filter(user => {
         return user.streamData.stream;
       });

       return Object.assign({},state,{filteredData});

    case SHOW_ALL:
    return state.pristine;

  }
  return state;
}
```

This code has a lot of defensive Object.assign and is far from production code, but I hope it points you in the right track.